# A movie where two sisters get a magical dress

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

A long time ago I have watched one very beautiful movie but I can't find it now. It's something about two blonde sisters, the older one was extremely lazy but the younger one was very diligent and somehow they were transported to another dimension and an old women gave a beautiful golden dress to a younger sister. She didn't care and she gave her dress to her sister but it would get dirty every time the lazy sister puts it on.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Take a moment a [read our guide on story ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62709) to see if you can remember any other details

Comment: This sounds a bit like an adaptation of *Frau Holler*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for the 2003 version of [*Frau Holle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frau_Holle#Film_adaptations)

As with the original tale, the first girl, industrious, falls into a well while trying to retrieve a spindle, and lands by Frau Holle's house and serves well before being sent back with a golden dress. Her stepsister, lazy, returns with a dress that never comes clean. However, the stepsister has brown hair.

I found out about *Frau Holle* by searching for *fantasy film sisters golden dress "lazy sister"* and then I looked for an adaptation with a golden dress (versus the original tale that employed a "shower of gold" upon her arrival or later versions where gold was emitted when she spoke).